# What does 'adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080' command do?

Tags: android, adb

While working on Android development, I have come across the command `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` many times. What does it actually do? and why 8080?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically means that the requests on specific port on the host will be forwarded to a specific port on the device.
Where the first port is the host and the second one is the device port.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports)

> forwarding of requests on a specific host port to a different port on an emulator/device instance